# What is Satan Doing Here?

Tags: california-gold-rush-2

In the first 'bonus mine' of *California Gold Rush 2*, after finding my way through a veritable maze of impenetrable rock formations, I managed to catch up with Satan.  What on Earth is he doing down here?

[image: Satan appears to be enjoying the comfort of his stone lazyboy down here in my mines.]

Does he have any kind of significance in the context of the game?  Is seeing Satan a sign that something is about to happen?  Is there something else nearby?

Comment: What exactly do you do in your free time that you've wound up  in Hell?

Comment: @Wipqozn Make inappropriate tags :D?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes inappropriately awesome tags

Comment: Well, in traditional medieval Christian mythology (really, outright stolen from Greek mythology) Hell is supposed to be beneath the Earth. So if you dig down deep enough, you will find Satan the Devil. Have you tried trading your soul for a high score?

Comment: you know, same stuff you do on your days off, Chillin', hangin', reading his mail, so on.

Comment: He is pondering how to kill you before you finish the game. You'll find out as you get to the end.

Comment: @gnomeslice as long as this remains the only question about this game, the tag will just disappear again. I'd *strongly* suggest editing the question itself to include the game title.

Comment: He is most likely tryin to overpower god and take over the world...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a navigate a *maze* to get this far, and just past Satan was a large pile of gold.  I'm not quite sure why the developers chose 'Satan' over anything else, but as far as I can tell, this is just a random thing put in at the end of the extremely challenging maze of rock, just before a large vein of Gold.  Maybe it's his personal stash?

Answer (score 4):

Well if you really want to know... There was a flux in the space-time continuum which caused the chain of event that led Satan to Hell to break. This created a wormhole that sucked only Satan up, and closed up shortly after. The wormhole led to this exact spot. Now he is trapped in a tiny, prison

Or it could be the artist trying to add a little humor into the game.

**It's the latter**, but hey, it's good to have a little imagination. xD